# Dynamic group by query

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I need to fire a dynamic group by query using an array.

```
a=['Branch','Company','Name'];
```

now , I need the query like

```
"select Branch,Company,Name,count(Name) as count from myTable group by Branch,Company,Name;"
```

Kindly suggest!!

Comment: What language are you using? And is the database MySQL or SQLite?

Comment: @peterm No, you would get 1 if you have `COUNT(DISTINCT Name)`. `COUNT(Name)` will get every non-NULL Names (correct result except for NULL Name). `COUNT(*)` will return all corresponding records (correct option).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your initial question data:

```
a=['Branch','Company','Name'];

function addCount(a) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        str=a.join(", ");
        tx.executeSql("select "+str+",count(*) as count from documentProperty GROUP BY "+str+";", [], function (tx, result) {
            if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = result.rows.item(i);
                    console.log(row);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

String quryString = "select Branch,Company,Name,count(Name) as count from myTable group by " ;

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    quryString =quryString +a[i];
```

now use quryString and fire your query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,
I tried and finally got my result from the following code.

```
jsonString=[{"field":"Branch"},{"field":"Company"},{"field":"Name"}]

function addCount(jsonString){
    var a=[];
    var str="";
    $.each(jsonString,function (i,result){
        a.push(result.field);
        if(i == jsonString.length-1){
            str += result.field; 
        } else{
             str += result.field+",";
        }
    });
          db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var q=(a.length-1);

            var query="select "+str+",count("+a[q]+") as count from documentProperty GROUP BY "+str+";";        console.log(query);
            tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, result) {
                if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                        var row = result.rows.item(i);
                        console.log(row);
                    }
                }
            });
         });

}
```

Comment: You should use `COUNT(*)`! Easier and gives correct results when column value is null. And will greatly simplify your program.